# Update route not working on merged express router params

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mern

I'm learning the MERN stack and encountered an issue on the edit route of my child router.

I have the below model schemas in `songs.js` and `students.js` files:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    instrument: String,
    songs: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Song'
    }]
});

const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);
module.exports = Student;
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const songSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    img: String
})

const Song = mongoose.model('Song', songSchema);
module.exports = Song
```

And I have `songs.js` and `students.js` files for my routers, with mergeParams set to true for my songs router `const songs = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });`. I'm attaching it to the students router like this:

```
students.use('/:id/songs', songs);
```

e.g., my url parameters become `students/student1/songs/song1`

All of my other routes are working, but on the update route of my songs router I'm getting an error "TypeError: Student.findById is not a function" when I redirect back to the song's index view. My edit and update routes 
 are below:

```
songs.get('/:songId/edit', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const findSong = Song.findById(req.params.songId);
        const findStudent = Student.findById = (req.params.id);
        const [foundSong, foundStudent] = await Promise.all([findSong, findStudent]);
        res.render('songs/edit', {
            student: foundStudent,
            song: foundSong
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

songs.put('/:songId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updateSong = await Song.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.songId, req.body, { new: true });
        res.redirect('/students/' + req.params.id + '/songs');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what's causing the error here, my delete route is set up similarly and is working. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: '/:songId/edit' route is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rote (req.params.id) is not defining.

```
songs.get('/:songId/edit', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const findSong = Song.findById(req.params.songId);
        **const findStudent = Student.findById = (req.params.id);**
        const [foundSong, foundStudent] = await Promise.all([findSong, findStudent]);
        res.render('songs/edit', {
            student: foundStudent,
            song: foundSong
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```